# How to solve: Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, semaphore, cancellation-token

I am trying to implement semaphore slim for a set of tasks that are meant to request some data to an external API. The data might have different formats, so the plan is to return `HttpResponseMessage`, so the converter (JSON converter) will deal with it.
However I am getting the mentioned error on the return and I have no idea what to do:

```
tasks.Add(
Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Run(() =>
{
    semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
    
    try{
        return (SetupRequestAsync(request, HttpMethod.Get));
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
    finally { semaphoreSlim.Release();  }
    
}, cancelTok
));
```

`cancelTok` is a cancellation token that is meant to stop creating threads once we got a valid result from server through `SetupRequestAsync` (which is meant to return an `HttpResponseMessage`).

Edit: return has an underline in red, marking that there is an error, when I hover over, the error is shown.

[image: error]

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error in the title. And calling `WaitAsync` without `await` is usually an incorrect usage.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the lambda `async` and then `await` the calls inside it. Do not swallow and rethrow exceptions, all it does is wipe the stack trace.

```cs
var task = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync(cancelTok);
        return await SetupRequestAsync(request, HttpMethod.Get);
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphoreSlim.Release();
    }
}, cancelTok);
tasks.Add(task);
```